# sign in liferay 6.2 but authentication must take place by user defined table data

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I want to sign in liferay by using userid and password provided by me means a table contains data about password and userid. I am trying to achieving this by using ext but first time I am using ext so if any one having any code or already developed such application then please help me to how I will authenticate user by using my table credentials not liferay default table user_.

Thanks

Asif Aftab

Answer (score 1):

Implement the Authenticator Class like described

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Authentication%20Pipeline

See the source code of `com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LDAPAuth`:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/LDAPAuth.java

And this can help you too:
https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/25186934

Comment: Thank you so much mark I will check and let u know that what is the result.